# Why the eigenvalue output is different for tensorflow and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, eigenvalue

I tried to calculate Eigenvalues for matrix using both numpy and tensorflow but I am getting different eigenvalues for each implementation. Below are the details

```
A=([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

EigenValues of A with numpy are `[0,6,0]`

EigenValues of A with tensorflow are `[ 0.30797836,  0.64310414,  5.04891825]`

I used `tf.self_adjoint_eig` for tensorflow implementation and `numpy.linalg.eig` for numpy implementation.

Comment: Your matrix is not self adjoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From description of the function:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#self_adjoint_eig

> Calculates the Eigen Decomposition of a square Self-Adjoint matrix.
>
> Only the lower-triangular part of the input will be used in this case.
>   The upper-triangular part will not be read.

Therefore TensorFlow's `self_adjoint_eig` on your matrix is equivalent to numpy's `eig` of the following matrix

> ({1,1,1},{1,2,2},{1,2,3})